# Post-launch shopify theme development

Tags: git, shopify

I have created my own shopify theme and having now published the website I would like to continue developing and adding features to it.

Initially I thought the best way to set this up would be as follows:

1. In git, create a new development branch away from master
2. In the dev branch, change the config.yml to point to a development theme hosted on shopify, through which changes made can be previewed more or less live.
3. Once the changes are made and tested, merge the branch back in and then update the live theme on shopify, remembering also to update the master branch version of config.yml to point to the live theme again.

This seems a bit cumbersome to me and could potentially lead to accidentally changing something on the live theme if I initially forget to change config settings.

Is there a more robust way of setting up for post launch development on shopify that perhaps I have not considered?

Thanks.

Comment: Git is not a configuration management system. Keep two separate `config.yml` files, one that is always live and one for development previews.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - so in practical terms I suppose that means I should keep config.yml untracked and if I need to clone either repository to a new location, acquire a local copy of the config file seperately. (It is necessary to have a local copy as to point the shopify_theme console tool to the correct location).